# How difficult is it to choose an ORM for Node.js? Or Node.js lacks a mature ORM

Tags: node.js, orm, typeorm, mikro-orm

I have a production project to develop. It's an e-commerce site.
My current stack:

1. Node.js
2. TypeScript
3. PostgreSQL

Now I have to choose an ORM for this project.
I think I have two options:

1. **TypeORM.** I've used this ORM before. It's good and stable software, but TypeORM has had [maintenance issues for a while](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3267).  I'm not sure about the future of this ORM.
2. **MikroORM.** TypeORM lacks some useful features like @Filters (scopes) and bulk subscribers, while MikroORM on the other hand has these features or alternatives (see [filters](https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/d658200732a02fbedda3429a6f26f5799c7cb75d/docs/docs/filters.md) and [alternative to bulk subscribers](https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/702)). But MikroORM is less popular and relatively new. And many of MikroORM's features are still in [alpha](https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/issues/527)

#### Summary

ORM with lack of maintenance and features but stable or ORM with great maintenance, new features, but not battle-tested.
Which option is better? Or maybe there are some alternatives?

Answer (score 14):

You can check **Sequelize** - https://sequelize.org, it has a TypeScript support, but the syntax is kind of ugly in my opinion.
Among the three, Sequelize is the most mature ORM.

**TypeORM** is very nice, but has some major bugs like this - https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3095. I came across to same or maybe similar problem related with saving one to many relations which i think is one of the most important features of every ORM and it must works properly.

I used **MikroORM** for a while - Again there are some minor problems which fortunately will be fixed in version 4. Overall, most of the features works properly and almost all of the problems that i had was resolved very quickly after reporting them on github.

Answer (score 7):

I recommend [Prisma](https://www.prisma.io/), a new NodeJS ORM with great features and documentation.

Comment: DId you use it with a REST-API? I have a pretty hard time with it atm, when I want to use it's interfaces in a typescript client

Comment: I have bad experience using this. It has bugs that already fixed in the previous version long time ago but it happened again int the new version. Now still looking for the better option, less of bugs is my priority.

Answer (score 1):

there are a orm named [@gradii/fedaco](https://github.com/gradii/fedaco). code converted from laravel eloquent. currently still in wip

actually right now I have no time and interest take long time to maintain this project.
typescript code and part of test is not published to public.

Comment: If you're not going to maintain it then why are you recommending it?

Comment: I have no enough time to maintain. waiting some to take control. typescript source code have been public